# Локальное сохранение документа для последующей печати

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, html, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с нетривиальной задачей — написать программу для редактирования документа (сметная программа) с последующим выводом результата на печать (при условии отсутствия интернета). Решил сделать браузер-ориентированное решение, но начал ловить «фейлы» на этапе вывода документа на печать.

Для хранения редактируемых версий использую localStorage, а вот при попытке вывести на печать начинается «катавасия» — каждый браузер пытается по своему определить правила и разметку печатного образца, **[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) print** не спасает, Opera на MacOS вообще не желает печатать более одной страницы.

Постепенно пришел к выводу, что нужно или итправлять данные стороннему классу для генерации PDF (т.к. именно этот формат идеально подходит для печати), или делать а-ля скриншот всей страницы в `*.png/*.bmp/*.tiff`. Но беда в том, что все найденные решения завязаны на **POST** серверу, а мне критично использование локальной версии без необходимости устанавливать веб-сервер.

В общем, если сталкивались с чем-то подобным или есть свежие идеи, буду рад совету.

Comment: чтоб избежать катавасии, настройте один раз параметры печати для пользователя, во всех браузерах будет одинаково (просто в них дефолты разные, поэтому и едет разметка). имеется в виду рабочие места надо настраивать, браузеры.

Comment: Так и делал, полпачки SvetoCopy уже извел, наверное, пытаясь добиться похожести. Особенно с Opera. Но все равно, даже если этот вопрос решить, при пагинации на выводе на печать появляется «лесенка» из первой строчки на новых страницах.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант rtf? Слетают сами стили? Выводите на принт без стилей, таблицами.

Comment: 1) а как автоматизировать HTML (+CSS) в rtf?
2) Смета большая, 160 пунктов. Таблицей и вывожу. Неизменно появляется лесенка в некоторых первых строках на новых страницах при разбиении.

Comment: тут уже гугл в помощь, перенос строк и формирование. и не важно насколько она большая. как вариант в сторону excel-я не смотрели?

Comment: Увы, важно — чтобы знать, какую строку перенести, нужно точно знать, где будет разрыв страницы. Писать правила для всех браузеров как-то не улыбается (а уж тем более эти правила вычислять).
Раньше я использовал TCPDF-класс PHP (пример на http://alphatrust.ru/nashi-uslugi/prajs/), все было восхитительно, на выходе получался православный *.pdf без проблем с пагинацией. НО сейчас нужно сделать то же самое, но только без серверной части.  
Кстати, page-break-* тоже оказался бесполезной вещью.

Comment: Сейчас методом тыка выяснил, что проблема возникает только при рисовании рамки у таблицы (а она нужна). Без нее строка не «плывет».

Comment: то есть если рамка есть то все норм? а page-break можно забить например на 30 (только есть вероятность что разрыв в последней странице кривой будет)

Comment: наоборот, прописываю *border* и начинаются пляски. А рамка нужна :(  
page-break работает только в Opera (да и то, извиняюсь, через з**ницу).